# Gutenberg Block add element in the Editor inside InnerBlocks after div - editor-block-list

Tags: plugin-development, block-editor

I want to wrap the InnerBlocks content in the editor with a custom React Element, but it is not rendering as I need it.

My code (simplified):

```
edit: ( props ) => {
   const {
     attributes:
     { options,
       otherAttributes,
     }, setAttributes, className } = props;

return (
<div className={`${options} ${otherAttributes}`} >
   <MyElement>
       <InnerBlocks />
   </MyElement>
</div>
);
},
```

The html output in wordpress editor comes out simplified as

```
<div class="my element classses">
    <div class="more sub classes from my element">
        <div class="my element">

            <div class="editor-inner-blocks block-editor-inner-blocks">

                <div class="editor-block-list__layout block-editor-block-list__layout">

                    <!-- actual inner blocks html comes out here -->
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>

                </div>

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

But I need my custom element to be rendered inside the editors innerblock divs just before the list of innerblocks so it appears like this

```
<div class="editor-inner-blocks block-editor-inner-blocks">

    <div class="editor-block-list__layout block-editor-block-list__layout">

        <div class="my element classses">
            <div class="more sub classes from my element">
                <div class="my element">

                    <!-- actual inner blocks list comes out here -->
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>
                    <div class="wp-block editor-block-list__block block-editor-block-list__block is-selected">
                        ...innerblock content many divs etc.
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

Is there a filter that might allow something like this? Or an attribute inside InnerBlocks that can be used? Any ideas?

Comment: I know it's a complex question to get across so any help on how I can portray it better is most welcome.

Comment: You want to modify the HTML output in the editor? Im afraid it's not going to be possible... Could you explain what are you trying to achieve, why is it necessary to adapt to the current HTML? Thanks.

Comment: @Alvaro I don't want to modify the HTML output necessarily. For example using [react-slick](https://react-slick.neostack.com/) around all of the innerblocks in the editor.

Comment: What should each slide contain? Each of the appended blocks (children of your root block)?

Comment: Correct, each child(innerblock) would be a slide.